# Kubernetes Autoscaling not recognizing Heapster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster that I'm trying to build from scratch without using their build scripts. Pretty much everything is working except for autoscaling. For some reason the control-manager can't find or doesn't know heapster is running.

I have a ticket open but it seems no responses

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18652

**UPDATE**: the issue has been answered on Github

Things I have setup.

Here is a list of all the pods currently

```
[root@kube-master test] [dev] # kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE        NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default          my-nginx-8kmlz                        1/1       Running   0          11h
default          my-nginx-z8cxb                        1/1       Running   0          11h
kube-system      heapster-v10-vdc1v                    3/3       Running   0          11h
kube-system      kube-apiserver-10.122.0.20            1/1       Running   0          4d
kube-system      kube-controller-manager-10.122.0.20   1/1       Running   1          9h
kube-system      kube-dns-6iw3a                        4/4       Running   0          4d
kube-system      kube-proxy-10.122.0.20                1/1       Running   0          3d
kube-system      kube-proxy-10.122.42.163              1/1       Running   0          4d
kube-system      kube-proxy-10.122.43.138              1/1       Running   1          4d
kube-system      kube-scheduler-10.122.0.20            1/1       Running   1          4d
```

So heapster is running against my proxy and I can access

```
http://10.122.0.20:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/api/v1/model/namespaces/default/pods/my-nginx-8kmlz/stats
```

It returns stats about the pod.

I'm really not sure what i am missing.

Here is what the output of a autoscale looks like

```
[root@kube-master test] [dev] # kubectl get hpa
NAME       REFERENCE                              TARGET    CURRENT     MINPODS   MAXPODS   AGE
my-nginx   ReplicationController/my-nginx/scale   80%       <waiting>   1         5         22h
```

In my controller logs the only thing I really see is

```
W1224 18:27:43.425126       1 horizontal.go:185] Failed to reconcile my-nginx: failed to compute desired number of replicas based on CPU utilization for ReplicationController/default/my-nginx: failed to get cpu utilization: failed to get CPU consumption and request: some pods do not have request for cpu
```

Comment: is there a reason you did not accept anon's answer?

Comment: This questions should somehow get an accepted answer from the github issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign cpu request / limit for  pods in deployment file example

resources: 
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            cpu: "250m"

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that `heapster` is deprecated since Kubernetes 1.13. It should be replaced with https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the limits and requests for cpu and memory for Horizontal pod Autoscaler to work

Answer (score -1):

Some time this happen because resource metrics not enabled.

you can verify with `blow` command:

```
kubectl top pod -n <namespace>
```

if you are getting  pods then metrics is enabled:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/#resource-metrics-pipeline